# Spring State Machine: possible events

Tags: spring, spring-statemachine

is it possible to get the list of possible events from a current state?

```
StateMachine<State, Event> stateMachine = stateMachineService.acquireStateMachine(machineId);
stateMachine.sendEvent(event);

stateMachine.getState()  // get possible events from State
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only solution i found is:

```
stateMachine.getTransitions().stream()
            .filter(transition -> transition.getSource().getId().equals(stateMachine.getState().getId()))
            .map(transition -> transition.getTrigger().getEvent())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```